# Lost passport with Schengen D visa

Tags: visas, long-stay-visas

I hope someone can help me here!

I'm Brazilian, I have a Schengen D visa for Portugal, but this weekend I visited Belgium. I kept my passport inside my backpack, but it got stolen. I already went to the police station and filed a report and called the Brazilian embassy, but they say they can't help me today, only tomorrow morning.

The problem is, I was supposed to be back in Portugal tomorrow at 3pm, and since my backpack got stolen I have no money with me.

I got pictures of my passport and the visa, but that's it.

How screwed am I? Do you think I have any chance on getting a passport, or some travel document in time?

Thank you!

Comment: I am be curious how did it go. Have you managed to make your flight on time, or after Brazil embassy you have had to go to the Portuguese embassy.

Answer (score 2):

It is usual for people to get their documents stolen.

Get to the embassy the earliest possible in the morning. Better earlier than their opening hours as there might be a queue.

They will be able *at least* to issue you with an emergency travel document.

Anything is possible as I once was issued in 3h a replacement passport, however I was registered in that consulate, and it is not your typical situation.

I would bet you will be issued at least emergency travel papers, and getting to Portugal, with your copy of the documents and their computer records, you will be granted at least temporary entry to fix the situation.

Nevertheless, get early to the embassy, as they are used to deal with these situations and will guide you better in what you need to do. Do not forget to have on you all the relevant documentation *and* the flight tickets/reservations. If they are electronic, print them out today, maybe in the hotel.

Have also at hand at least 250-300 Euros in cash just in case. You have to pay the cost of the emergency documents and depending on the location of the embassy you might need to catch a taxi to the airport to get to your flight on time, which can be quite costly in European capitals. Withdraw the cash before midnight today as you can hit daily withdraw limits.

Lastly, be aware of time management. Besides arriving early to the embassy, you will also have to arrive early to the airport, as you are not carrying with you an eletronic passport.